# send the value of the field from an interactive grid to another page and store it in an item with Javascript and Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I currently save the value of a field of the grid in an item (P5_VALUE),send it to another page (page 6) and store it in an item (P6_VALUE) through a button

Action: Redirect to Page in this application.

Target: Page in this application , Page: 6, set Items: NAME: P5_VALUE, VALUE: P6_VALUE, Action: Reset Pagination. This is the url that is generated: http://ip:port/ords/app/system/page?p5_value=61&clear=RP&session=12518184703789

But now I want to do the same with APEX$ROW_SELECTOR. With this code I have been able to add an action to the grid and get the value of the field but I do not know how to send it to the other page and assign the value to the other item

```
var view = apex.region("ig-emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid"),
menu$ = view.rowActionMenu$;

menu$.menu("option").items.push({
 type:"action",
 label:"Get Emp No",
 icon: "fa fa-close",
 action: function(menu, element) {
                     var record = view.getContextRecord( element )[0];
                     var val1 = view.model.getValue(record, "EMPNO");
                                 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below approach to achieve this:

1. Let me start by adding some more lines to your code.

```
var view = apex.region("ig-emp").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid"),
menu$ = view.rowActionMenu$;

menu$.menu("option").items.push({
 type:"action",
 label:"Get Emp No",
 icon: "fa fa-close",
 action: function(menu, element) {
                     var record = view.getContextRecord( element )[0];
                     var val1 = view.model.getValue(record, "EMPNO");
                     apex.page.submit({
                          request:"NAVIGATE",
                          set:{"P1_EMPNO":val1},
                          showWait: true
                     }); 
                                 }
 });
```

**Note: in the above code replace P1_EMPNO with your page item name.**'

2. Create a Branch -> Type: Page or URL(Redirect).
3. Select the page number to redirect and set the value of the current page item to the new page item. Refer below screen shot for example.

[image]

4. In the Server-side condition, select the Type as Request = Value and provide the value as NAVIGATE. Refer below screen shot.

[image]